# Formula to change the layout of a Google Sheet: Transpose & Split

Tags: google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, transpose, flatten

I would like to convert data collected in Sheet1 so it look like Sheet2.

#### Sheet1 - Data populated from Google Form.

- This sheet contains the attendance of which employees participated in a specific class.
- This sheet contains over 50,000 rows.
- Class ID are unique for each row.
- The same Employee ID can be found in multiple rows

  - Notice Employee ID "123456" is found in class X123456, and ZZ974547

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **Date** | **Class ID** | **Employee ID's** |
| 2 | 4/26/2021 6:47:13 | X123456 | 123456 896779 835906 TMP880997 908613 882853 |
| 3 | 4/26/2021 17:18:57 | Y123456 | 227583 233482 218680 226955 225310 227569 227582 |
| 4 | 4/26/2021 18:01:30 | XYZ123456 | 201032 232863 232848 TMP232845 |
| 5 | 4/27/2021 12:24:29 | X123457 | 188809 224046 232861 232846 |
| 6 | 4/28/2021 10:56:28 | X123458 | 210975 |
| 7 | 5/26/2021 10:29:31 | ZZ974547 | 123456 955725 961714 956114 955986 959287 955748 |

#### Sheet2 - Expected outcome using a formula

- Results sorted by timestamp.
- Count the number of Employee ID's within a Class ID.
- Then duplicate the Class ID the same number of times.

  - Class ID X123456 contains 6 Employee ID's, so X123456 is repeated 6 times (1/row)
  - Class ID Y123456 contains 7 Employee ID's, so Y123456 is repeated 7 times (1/row)

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **Class ID** | **Employee ID** |
| 2 | X123456 | 123456 |
| 3 | X123456 | 896779 |
| 4 | X123456 | 835906 |
| 5 | X123456 | TMP880997 |
| 6 | X123456 | 908613 |
| 7 | X123456 | 882853 |
| 8 | Y123456 | 227583 |
| 9 | Y123456 | 233482 |
| 10 | Y123456 | 218680 |
| 11 | Y123456 | 226955 |
| 12 | Y123456 | 225310 |
| 13 | Y123456 | 227569 |
| 14 | Y123456 | 227582 |
| 15 | XYZ123456 | 201032 |
| 16 | XYZ123456 | 232863 |
| 17 | XYZ123456 | 232848 |
| 18 | XYZ123456 | TMP232845 |

#### Here are the current formulas I have tried...

Sheet2!A2 `=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(B2:B &" ",COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(C2:C," "))))," "))`

Sheet2!B2 `=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(C2:C," "))`

These formulas work for the first Class ID, but not for the remaining Class ID's. I tried wrapping them with `ARRAYFORMULA()` but that did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(D2:D, " "))="",,
 C2:C&"×"&SPLIT(D2:D, " "))), "×"), "where Col2 is not null"))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(
 SPLIT(D2:D, " "))="",,C2:C&"×"&SPLIT(D2:D, " ")&"♦")), "×"), 
 "where Col2 is not null"), "♦", ))
```

Comment: Works perfectly for the examples shared above! Thanks player0. After running this on the real sheet, I noticed there was some Employee ID's missing. The missing ID's that were missing contain letters in-front of the Employee ID (Ex: TMP123456). I have added this variable into my question. As for your formula, I tried adding `TO_TEXT` for each of the ranges, but that did not work. What function in your formula is omitting text from being displayed? Thanks :)

Comment: @JamesReed68 answer updated

Comment: You sir are a legend. I wish one day I can create formulas like you.